incompatible types: 'TBaseVirtualTree' and 'TVTBaseAncestorVcl'
I have updated to Delphi 12 and the latest VirtualTreeview and get an error when trying to get the IAccessibles. The code in virtualtrees.BaseAncestorVCL is as follows:
 // Create the IAccessibles for the tree view and tree view items, if necessary.
    if Accessible = nil then
        Accessible :=   VTAccessibilityFactory.GetAccessibilityFactory.CreateIAccessible(Self);

// Self=TVTBaseAncestorVcl but Atree is expected
    
  function TVTAccessibilityFactory.CreateIAccessible(ATree: TBaseVirtualTree): IAccessible;


[dcc32 Error] VirtualTrees.BaseAncestorVcl.pas(525): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBaseVirtualTree' and 'TVTBaseAncestorVcl'

